# Java: simple string to date parsing fails with exception

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

This is my method:

```
  @Test
  public void convertUpdateDateToDateTest() {
    String updateDate = "11-Dec-2015";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    try {
      Date date = formatter.parse(updateDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I don't understand why this is not working.

Exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11-Dec-2015"
```

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. These basic date-time questions have been answered many times over already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a `Locale` different then English specified as your Java default one in which case parsing won't recognize English month names.

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/11fQFb)